# Arquivo STYLE.XML android Studio 2023

Tags: android-studio, xml

Boa noite,

Comecei estudar Desenvolvimento mobile, com um curso da udedmy, porém o instrutor ao criar um projeto EMPTY VIEW ACTIVITY, ele modifica um arquivo STYLE.XML. E quando eu crio um projeto, o nao vem esse arquivo, eu fucei em tudo mas nao achei. (Estou usando a versao giraffe do android studio).

Alguem pode me ajudar, por favor?

Nao estou conseguindo prosseguir com o curso pq em todas as aulas ele modifica esse arqruivo, e eu nao consigo acompanhar ele.